# Try to call rake file with cronjob

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, redmine

This I am starting in the prompt:

```
root@debian{/usr/share}:rake /usr/share/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_pop3 RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail.dd.com port=995 username=test password=D ssl=true project=Helpdesk --trace
```

And this is the trace for it:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:684:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `'
```

When I go into the folder /usr/share/redmine then it works without a problem.

Do i call it false?

Edit: The Image from the filesystem:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/share/redmine/Rakefile`exists? Also note Linux file system is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have added a screenshot from the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it correctly. Go to the redmine directory and omit the file since rake will find Rakefile itself.

```
root@debian{/usr/share/redmine}:rake redmine:email:receive_pop3 ...
```

Use -f or --rakefile if the Rakefile has a different name:

```
root@debian{/usr/share/redmine}:rake -f different_rake_file_name redmine:email:receive_pop3 ...
```

From the [doc](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/command_line_usage_rdoc.html):

> % rake [options ...]  [VAR=VALUE ...]  [targets ...]
>
> ...
>
> --rakefile filename (-f)
>
> Use filename as the name of the rakefile. The default rakefile names are rakefile and Rakefile (with rakefile taking precedence). If
>   the rakefile is not found in the current directory, rake will search
>   parent directories for a match. The directory where the Rakefile is
>   found will become the current directory for the actions executed in
>   the Rakefile.